# The underlying set of an induced metric space is both closed and open in itself

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a following reasoning in metric space:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. Let $(A, d')$ be the metric space induced from $d$. Then $A = X \cap A$. Because $X$ is both closed and open in $X$, $A$ is both closed and open in $A$.

Could you please confirm if it is correct? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically sound, but there's something that bothers me. You seem happy to assume that, for any metric space $X$, $X$ is closed and open within itself. You also seem happy to call the subset $A$ of $X$ a metric space when equipped with the induced metric. This being the case, surely proving $A$ is closed and open in $A$ is redundant, when you're assuming this is true for an arbitrary metric space $X$ to begin with?

Comment: From your answer, I got that: There exists a metric space $(X,d)$ that $X$ is not closed in itself or $X$ is not open in itself. A natural question arises in my mind: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space  such that $X$ is not closed in itself, is there a subset $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung No sorry, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that, the argument should be "1. Every metric space $(X, d)$ is closed and open in itself, 2. $(A, d')$ is a metric space, therefore 3. $A$ is closed and open in $(A, d')$." Your argument, while logically fine, seems circuitous.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much! I'm clear ::)))

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The underlying set for any topological space is both closed and open in itself.  It will still be so for metric spaces, and it will still be so for subspaces.